# TikZ Externalize breaks path fading

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-external

I'm using the `\usetikzlibrary{external}` command because my document has a lot of resource hogging TikZ pictures and with this command typesetting is much faster. The problem is that with the External Library, the fading draws disappear from the compiled pdf. To use the library I compile with the `--shell-escape` option.

It's very strange because in pictures folder where External saves the single pdf files, there is the faded picture correctly rendered, but the same picture has no fading at all in the main pdf file.

Of course, disabling the External library commenting the line `\tikzexternalize[prefix=figures/]` the picture is rendered correctly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings,calc,positioning,external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=figures/] 

\newcommand{\dd}[1]{\mathrm{d}{#1}\;}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
  cone_inverted/.pic={
    \shade[bottom color=blue!5!white,top color=blue!40!white,opacity=0.3] (-1,-3) arc (180:360:.5cm and .25cm) -- (0,0) -- cycle;
        \draw (-1,-3) arc (180:360:.5cm and .25cm) -- (0,0) -- cycle;
        \draw[dashed] (-1,-3) arc (180:0:.5cm and 0.25cm);
        \node (n) at (-.6, -3.7) {$\dd{N}$};
        \node (o) at (.3, -1) {$\dd{\Omega}$};
    },
    rect/.pic = {
    \fill[gray!50] (0,-1) --(0.3,-1) -- (0.3,1)--(0,1) -- cycle; 
    }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]

    \fill[purple, path fading=west]
    (0,-.1) -- (5,-.1) -- (5,-.2) -- (5.5,0) -- (5,.2) -- (5,.1) -- (0,.1) -- (0,-.1);

    \fill[blue!50, path fading=west]
    (7,-.1) -- (12,-.1) -- (12,-.2) -- (12.5,0) -- (12,.2) -- (12,.1) -- (7,.1) -- (7,-.1);
    \node at (2.5,-0.5) {$\Phi_0 = \frac{\text{fotoni}}{\SI{}{\second\centi\meter\squared}}$};
    \node at (9.5,-0.5) {$\Phi\ped{T}$};

    \coordinate (a) at (6,0);
    \path (a)+(20:.5) pic[rotate=120] {cone_inverted};
    \path (a)+(0:-0.2) pic {rect};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The picture `figures/document_title-figure0.pdf` is correctly displayed and looks like
[image]

while in the output file it looks like this

[image]

Any idea how to solve this strange behaviour?

Edit: I've also noticed that if I replace the line

```
  \fill[blue!50, path fading=west]
```

with

```
 \shade[left color=white, right color= blue!50]
```

there is the same issue. Instead if I use a different color instead of white, for example

```
 \shade[left color=red, right color= blue!50]
```

it works as expected. The mystery deepens.

Comment: Are you using the same engine or first PDFLaTeX then XeLaTeX or something like that ?

Comment: Always PDFLaTeX

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue using the posted code and pdfLaTeX. The only thing I changed was to use an existing sub-directory rather than `figures/`. (I used `ffigurau/`. The output is as expected with `pdflatex --shell-escape`. No problem at all.

Comment: Interesting.. I use Texpad with MacTex 2015 and all packages updated and the issue appears always with different documents, different tikz pictures and different PDF viewers. Maybe the are some problems with my configuration. Fortunately I solved with answer below.
However thanks for the check.

Comment: This seems to be still an issue. I'm trying to report it as a bug. https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/833

Comment: However it seems to be non-reproducible on some installations. So here's what I consider relevant: skim Version 1.5.6 (122) and
preview Version 11.0 (999.4)
pgf 3.1.5b
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019)
XeTeX 3.14159265-2.6-0.999991 (TeX Live 2019)
macOS Catalina 10.15.3 (19D76)

Comment: I've viewed the main.pdf file now on my Android phone with Adobe Acrobat 20.0.1.11139.
Both arrows show up there wonderfully. That gets me to the conclusion, that this is a viewer issue.

Answer (score 1):

After some experiments I found a workaround replacing the line

```
\fill[blue!50, path fading=west]
```

with

```
\shade[left color=blue!0, right color= blue!50]
```

Other methods seem not work (using External Library of course).

Comment: Thanks. The `\shade` workaround did the trick for me as well. - also using `xelatex` and `externalize`

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that `\tikzfading[name=fadeout, bottom color=transparent!0, top color=transparent!100]` may break tikzexternalize on some plattforms (with MikTeX on Windows 10 compilation never finishes). My (non-perfect) workaround is to place the shape on the lowest layer and to fade its color to white using `\draw[bottom color=black, top color=white]`.